# Trouble installing AMDGPU-PRO Ubuntu 16.04.2

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, dkms

Hey here are some infos first:
Ubuntu 16.04.2
Fresh Install
Kernel 4.8.0-41
AMD R9 285

I'm trying to install the AMDGPU-Pro driver without success. I tried 16.40, 16.50 and 16.60 none of them is working properly. After installing and restarting the system I'm getting no signal on my monitor, the system is running tho.

While running the install script im getting the following error:

```
Setting up dkms (2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.3) ...
    Setting up amdgpu-pro-dkms (16.40-348864) ...
    Loading new amdgpu-pro-16.40-348864 DKMS files...
    First Installation: checking all kernels...
    Building only for 4.8.0-41-generic
    Building for architecture x86_64
    Building initial module for 4.8.0-41-generic
    Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.8.0-41-generic (x86_64)
    Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.40-348864/build/make.log for more information.
```

This is the make.log:

```
DKMS make.log for amdgpu-pro-16.40-348864 for kernel 4.8.0-41-generic (x86_64)
Do 16. Mär 16:03:27 CET 2017
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-41-generic'
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.40-348864/build/built-in.o
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.40-348864/build/amd/amdgpu/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.40-348864/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_drv.o
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.40-348864/build/amd/amdgpu/../backport/backport.h:9:0,
                 from <command-line>:0:
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.40-348864/build/amd/amdgpu/../backport/include/kcl/kcl_ttm.h: In function ‘kcl_ttm_bo_reserve’:
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.40-348864/build/amd/amdgpu/../backport/include/kcl/kcl_ttm.h:109:9: error: too many arguments to function ‘ttm_bo_reserve’
  return ttm_bo_reserve(bo, interruptible, no_wait, false, ticket);
         ^
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.40-348864/build/amd/amdgpu/../backport/include/kcl/kcl_ttm.h:6:0,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.40-348864/build/amd/amdgpu/../backport/backport.h:9,
                 from <command-line>:0:
./include/drm/ttm/ttm_bo_driver.h:863:19: note: declared here
 static inline int ttm_bo_reserve(struct ttm_buffer_object *bo,
                   ^
scripts/Makefile.build:289: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.40-348864/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_drv.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.40-348864/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_drv.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:440: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.40-348864/build/amd/amdgpu' failed
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.40-348864/build/amd/amdgpu] Error 2
Makefile:1491: recipe for target '_module_/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.40-348864/build' failed
make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.40-348864/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-41-generic'
```

Does someone know how to fix it?